# How do I setup developer specific data in my Rails 3.2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

We have multiple developers working on our current app. The app uses data in the cloud. The service we use has an app_id and an app_key. We have a app_id, app_key pair on this remote cloud per environment (prod, dev, test). The issue is, when each dev needs to work on his/her own feature we don't want to share the same remote app (using the app_id, app_key pair). So, each dev needs their own pair on this remote service. The keys are stored in a yaml file:

```
development:
  id: 4321
  key: 321

test:
  id: 12345
  key: 123

production:
  id: <%= ENV['MASTER_ID'] %>
  key: <%= ENV['MASTER_KEY'] %>
```

How do I set it up so that when each developer starts working on a feature he/she will already have their own keys in THEIR dev environment and they won't need to copy/paste it back into this config file every time?

(we use git if that helps)

Comment: I don't think you can execute Ruby inside a YAML file ... I advise you to clone these files into `file.template.yml` and ask every developper to recreate this `file.yml` with their credentials and following the template. Also add the `file.yml` to the ignored files of your Version Control (Git, SVN, etc).

Comment: @MrYoshiji we're considering adding this file to the gitignore but I'm not sure that's ideal. We could also break it out into two files. One file will contain `production` and `test` keys. The other file will be for each developer and therefore is ignored by git. Still, looking for alternatives...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each developer should have a `app_keys.yml` in his local development drive, and then you just add it to .gitignore file so it won't be tracked by git.

Answer (score 0):

We follow the following design for having keys/info dependent on various work machines/servers etc.:

Define a variable in `environment.rb` which stores the `path` to the directory which has all the(or single) yml file(s) which each machine needs to have.

Wherever those keys are required to be loaded, the yml file is fetched through the path set in the `environment.rb` file.

The advantage here is that per system only single file needs to be modified during various `git` processes i.e. the env file storing the *path/to/keys/directory*. Each dev/server needs to have the template of the file in that directory to replicate those files and properly place the appropriate keys in those file by themselves.